# How can slideToggle() be properly implemented in my code in order to have the mobile view NavBar transition down when the menu button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried inserting a separate script at the bottom of my HTML code using class 'icon' and class 'fa fa bars'. But nothing seems to work. I used the basic code outline from w3schools and replaced "button" with "fa fa bars" and then altered the code variously and nothing came out correct.

Here is the code I tried to implement it in.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

$('#myTopnav a').on('click', function() {
  $('#myTopnav a').toggleClass(' responsive');
});

$(".icon").click(function() {
  $(".topnav").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: justify;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 60px 5px 60px;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #4286f4;
}

.active,
.active:focus {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #4286f4;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a:active,
.topnav a:visited {
  outline: 0 !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 8px;
    line-height: 15px;
    outline: 0;
  }
  .topnav {
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: height 2s;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: static;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 8px;
    line-height: 15px;
    outline: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#"><img src="Images/PlaceholderLogo.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your expected behavior ?

Comment: @SilentCoder My expected behavior is to create a NavBar similar to Apple.com's. Right now I have everything working properly expect the slide/transition animation. For some reason, in the code snippet, when you click the mobile NavBar menu button, the menu appears then hides immediately. This doesn't happen on the website itself for some reason.